# Generating a relation from second field in pig

Tags: union, apache-pig

I have performed a "group by" on a relation and the result is similar to the following:

```
    g1,{a1,a2,a3}
    g2,{b1,b2,b3,b4}
    g3,{c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6}
    ...
```

so the first field is the group and the second filed is a bag of tuples where each bag may have different number of elements. What I want to do is to generate a new relation which includes all the elements in the second fields. Therefore, the output will be:
B={a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,b4,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6}

Coud you help on this?

Sara

Comment: So you want to have one bag of all of the elements?  What was the point of grouping?

Comment: I do some processing on each group members (pairwise diff) and then want to take the union

Answer (score 0):

If you want what I think you want you are seeking to create a new relation where each of the tuples that was formerly in the bags from grouping is now an entire record.  To do this, use the `FLATTEN` operator, which blows up the bag into multiple records.  If you can assume that all of the tuples in the bags have the same schema, you can additionally `FLATTEN` those to promote the tuple elements to full-fledged fields:

If `A` is the result of the grouping, and

```
DESCRIBE A;
{(key:chararray, bag:{})}
```

You can do

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(bag) AS tuple;
```

Then to convert the tuples into full rows, do

```
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(tuple);
```

You can read more about `FLATTEN` [here](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449302641/advanced_pig_latin.html).

Answer (score 0):

In order to get to a result like what you started with, I did:

```
grunt> A = LOAD '../../../input/tuplesSample.txt' using PigStorage(' ') AS (grupo:chararray, charo:chararray);
grunt> DESCRIBE A;
A: {grupo: chararray,charo: chararray}
grunt> B = GROUP A by grupo;
grunt> DESCRIBE B;
B: {group: chararray,A: {(grupo: chararray,charo: chararray)}}
grunt> C = FOREACH B GENERATE $0 as grupo, $1.charo as charos;
grunt> DESCRIBE C;
C: {grupo: chararray,charos: {(charo: chararray)}}
grunt> DUMP C;
C: {grupo: chararray,charos: {(charo: chararray)}}
(g1,{(a1),(a2),(a3)})
(g2,{(b4),(b3),(b2),(b1)})
(g3,{(c4),(c5),(c6),(c2),(c1),(c3)})
```

Then I did this, to give you the new relation (`E` below) that contains all the elements in a single bag.

```
grunt> D = FOREACH C GENERATE FLATTEN($1) as charos;
grunt> DESCRIBE D;
D: {charos: chararray}

grunt> E = GROUP D ALL;
grunt> DESCRIBE E;
E: {group: chararray,D: {(charos: chararray)}}
grunt> DUMP E;
(all,{(c3),(c1),(c2),(c6),(c5),(c4),(b1),(b2),(b3),(b4),(a3),(a2),(a1)})
```